# How target an element with its href and class?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target a li with its href content like this :

```
$('#menu li:has(a[href*="content"])').addClass('myclass');
```

Now I'm trying to target the same element but with a particular class added to it. Can I use 'has' and 'hasClass' together? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, no need for hasClass:

```
$('#menu li.myClass:has(a[href*="content"])').addClass('myclass');
```

or if you want to target that `a`, use:

```
$('#menu li:has(a.myClass[href*="content"])').addClass('myclass');
```

Comment: @onerkript You can accept the answer too. Don't forget ;)

Comment: Will do, don't worry, 8 minutes left before I can accept. :)